# Wald test: Why do we assume normality of estimate

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normality-assumption, wald-test

Suppose, I am using Wald test to test following hypothesis. 
$$H0:\theta = \theta_0$$ 
$$H1:\theta \neq \theta_0$$

Given the MLE estimate $\hat{\theta}$ , Wald test makes the following normality assumption: $$\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta_0}{\hat{se}}\rightsquigarrow \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

Suppose $\theta = \theta^*$ is the true value of parameter, then for MLE estimate $\hat{\theta}$ we know: 
$$\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta^*}{\hat{se}}\rightsquigarrow \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

Why can we make the assumption of normality around $\theta_0$, when we know $\hat{\theta}$ is normal around $\theta^*$ and still trust the results?

Comment: You are misinterpreting the arrow symbol.  It means that the quantity approaches the N(0,1) distribution as n tends to infinity.  It is a central limit result. Now I will answer the question based on the proper interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

The implied result requires assuming the null hypothesis is true.  We need $\theta^*$ to equal $\theta_0$ and this will happen if the null hypothesis is true.  Otherwise, it will be a non-zero constant, say $m$. In that case, the asymptotic distribution will be $N(m,1)$.

Comment: Both $\theta^*$ and $\theta_0$ are fixed values, which have nothing to do with sample size $n$.

Comment: Sorry I meant that theta star would have to equal theta 0 i.e. the true theta is the null value of theta.  I will edit my post.